# JOOQ dynamic multiple values insert

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have a list of records and I need to insert it in one query with upsert like

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name, lastname) 
VALUES ('name1', 'lastname1'), ('name2', 'lastname2') 
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Not batch or merge and necessary with 'on conflict' logic

Answer (score 4):

Use the new jOOQ 3.15 [`InsertValuesStep2.valuesOfRows()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/InsertValuesStep2.html#valuesOfRows(java.util.Collection)):

```kotlin
insertInto(table1, table1.name, table1.lastname)
    .valuesOfRows(usersForInsert.map { DSL.row(it.name, it.lastname) })
    .onConflictDoNothing()
    .execute()
```

Answer (score -1):

Made it so clean with such approach in Kotlin :

```
insertInto(table1, table1.name, table1.lastname)
            .apply {
                usersForInsert.forEach { user ->
                    values(user.name, user.lastname)
                }
            }
            .onConflictDoNothing()
            .execute()
```

Thanks

Comment: This will not work without calling at least on values call outside the apply because execute() can only be called on the InsertValuesStepN<> generic.